# Apply HTML effects on detail view in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have detail view page like below

[image]

I want to show that relevant fields with HTML effects (if it has)

this is sample cshtml code for above view

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })     
            </div>
           </div>              
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameAr, Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameAr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR, new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })
            </div>
         </div>            
    }
```

Comment: There is not need for the 2nd parameter in you `LabelFor()` methods - can be just `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })` but the image you have shown has some `textarea` elements but the code snippet does not show them?

Comment: Extremely sorry , edited it

Comment: Is this view for editing? If not then you can use `@Html.Raw(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN)` (and put in in a div with borders etc if that's what you want visually)

Comment: No its details view , since I'm unaware to apply Rich Text Effets just using this , ill try ur  sugession

Comment: @StephenMuecke then I'm getting following error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: Oops, sorry that should be `@Html.Raw(Model.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN)`

Comment: And using `@Html.Label()` which creates `<label>` elements is not really appropriate (clicking on it wont set the the focus to the associated form control because there is no associated form control)

Comment: Now its working , I'd like mark as answer :) thanks lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view your creating is not for editing, then you can use `@Html.Raw()` to output the non-encoded html.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN)
```

If you also want the visual effect of the border, padding etc, then you can put this inside a `<div>` element and style it.

Side note: A `<label>` is an accessibility element associated with a form control (clicking on it sets focus to the associated control, but in this case you do not have any). Consider just using `<span>@Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn<span>`